# How can i return the URL using fetchCurrentURL in Vaadin

Tags: java, spring, lambda, client, vaadin

If im using fetchCurrentURL in Vaadin like that:

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage().fetchCurrentURL(url -> Notification.show(url.getPath()));
```

to get a Notification at the website with the current URL of the page as String, how then i can get this value back, i want something like:

```
String s = UI.getCurrent().getPage().fetchCurrentURL(url -> Notification.show(url.getPath()));
```

???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, if this is the right way in vaadin app, but as a workaround you can somewhat abuse mutable objects to achieve it.

```
class MutableObject {

  private String value;

  //getter,setter
}
```

Instantiate it outside the lambda and set the value inside the function:

```
MutableObject mutableObject = new MutableObject();
UI.getCurrent().getPage().fetchCurrentURL(url -> mutableObject.setValue(url.getPath()));
System.out.println(mutableObject.getValue());
```

Comment: Java already has at least two built-in variants of `MutableObject`. One is `AtomicReference<String>` and the other one in `String[1]`.

Comment: Yes, those are viable options, but still... `AtomicReference` holds volatile a reference, i don't think atomicity is needed here. `String[]` on the other hand is just unclear. Having readability in mind, i feel that a simple custom class is the best fit in this scenario.